# What is the connection between Higgs field and gravity?

Tags: gravity, higgs

The Higgs mechanism gives particles mass. Mass creates gravity. So I wonder if there's a connection between the two.

Comment: The Higgs is not the only source of mass, and mass is not the only source of gravity...

Comment: Adding to Mitchell's point, most of the mass that matter has comes from the *interactions* between particles. The Higgs only provides a small fraction of the mass of matter. For further understanding of how energy causes gravity, read about GR's stress-energy tensor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor and you will see that mass is the not the only source of gravity.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70596/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34532/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The Higgs mechanism is quantum mechanical. Gravity is not yet definitly quantized, one would need such a theory to examine how  the particles acquiring mass through the Higgs mechanism, are affecting the gravitational field before symemtry breaking and after the break. The only candidate theory I know studied at that level is string theories, see the complexity here https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9703202